# how to prevent deadlock when using wxCRIT_SECT_LOCKER

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock, critical-section

I'm writing a singleton Logger class in c++. this class provides logging API to multiple threads. to make it thread safe I'm using **wxCRIT_SECT_LOCKER** macro.

say I have this in my Logger class the following functions (simple example):

```
void Logger::error( string msg )
{
  wxCRIT_SECT_LOCKER(adapter_locker, gs_LogBufferShield);

  // do something such as getting/setting class members 
  m_err_cnt++;

  do_log("Error: " + msg);
}

void Logger::warning( string msg )
{
  wxCRIT_SECT_LOCKER(adapter_locker, gs_LogBufferShield);

  // do something such as getting/setting class members 
  m_warn_cnt++;

  do_log("Warning: " + msg);
}

void Logger::do_log( string msg )
{
  wxCRIT_SECT_LOCKER(adapter_locker, gs_LogBufferShield);

  // do something such as getting/setting class members 
  m_log_cnt++;


  cout << msg << endl;
}
```

**Problem:**

when *Logger::warning()* is called we'll enter the critical section twice, once in *Logger::warning()* and one more time in *Logger::do_log()*.

If you agree the problem is real and can cause deadlock, how can I avoid multiple locks (using wxCriticalSection class/macros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is often done is to create internal APIs that do not take locks that are called by the public APIs that do take the locks.

```
void Logger::error( string msg )
{
  wxCRIT_SECT_LOCKER(adapter_locker, gs_LogBufferShield);
  m_err_cnt++;
  do_log_internal("Error: " + msg);
}

void Logger::warning( string msg )
{
  wxCRIT_SECT_LOCKER(adapter_locker, gs_LogBufferShield);
  m_warn_cnt++;
  do_log_internal("Warning: " + msg);
}

void Logger::do_log( string msg )
{
  wxCRIT_SECT_LOCKER(adapter_locker, gs_LogBufferShield);
  do_log_internal(msg);
}

void Logger::do_log_internal( string msg )
{
  m_log_cnt++;
  cout << msg << endl;
}
```

However, for your problem, you may rather use `wxMutex` directly, and use the type `wxMUTEX_RECURSIVE` when you construct it. This way, a mutex has count. When the mutex is first locked, the count is set to 1. If the same thread grabs the mutex again, it increments a count. Releasing the mutex decrements the count. When the count reaches 0, the mutex is unlocked.

Comment: Thank u! I was just giving a simple example. all Logger function needs to be locked since they all get/set class members. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @ShaltielQuack: I expanded the answer a bit.

Comment: I was trying to do that. however it is not often easy to accomplish since your public functions may call other public functions as well. so your solution requires for each public method an internal one. Am i right?

Comment: @ShaltielQuack: Yes, the idea is that the public function takes the lock, and then calls the internal function.

Comment: So basically you double your class API. x public functions and x internal functions. I'm not too enthused implementing it that way. it is reasonable to be able to ask whether a section had been locked.

Comment: @ShaltielQuack: This is actually the bridge pattern, where the refined abstraction takes locks, and the concrete implementation does not.